# Wordpress - Cannot upload file

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, centos7

I have a problem with uploading file to my WordPress site.

```
The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2016/02.
```

The user for uploading is *nginx*. I checked it via PHP, too. Folder and content of it is owned by this user. I have also tried it with full permissions (`chmod 777`) but it is still not working.

This is my second site on the same server. The first one (also WordPress) is working fine. I can upload files there.

It sound to me there could be set something like `chroot` to a directory, but I was not able to find it out.

Comment: are your permissions set all the way down (recursively)? or specifically on 2016/02 only

Comment: Yes, the permissions and also owner is set recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few tips:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-upload-file?replies=4
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/media-upload-problem-the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-error?replies=42

Anyway, I tried it with **clean package of wordpress** and it works this time.

Answer (score 0):

Does your php.ini file set open_basedir to something restrictive? Something like this would be safe:

```
open_basedir = /tmp:/var/tmp:/var/www
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: I have just set it, but nothing have changed.